# mysql query string get 2 counts from selects

Tags: sql, mysql

i'm trying to create a query that allows me to get 2 counts from selects.

I have a table (name "warehouses") with the following design and data:

| nation | city |
| --- | --- |
| italy | roma |
| germany | berlin |
| italy | roma |
| france | paris |
| italy | torino |
| italy | firenze |

I would like to get the count of nation and the related count of city

example:

```
nation: italy 4
city: roma 2

nation: italy 4
city: torino 1

nation: italy 4
city: firenze 1
```

my attempt

```
select nation, city, count (nation), count (city)
from warehouses
```

but result is different than I would like...

```
select nation, city, count (nation), count (city)
from warehouses
```

Comment: Something like `WITH n AS ( SELECT nation, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM warehouses GROUP BY nation, city ), c AS ( SELECT nation, city, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM warehouses GROUP BY nation, city ) SELECT w.nation, w.city, n.cnt AS nation_count, c.cnt AS city_count FROM warehouses AS w INNER JOIN n ON n.nation = w.nation INNER JOIN c ON c.nation = w.nation AND c.city = w.city`

Comment: A query result is a table. So, next time, please show your result in table format, just as Dai has already converted the warehouses table content in your request for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT w.nation, w.city, c.nation_count, COUNT(w.city) as city_count
FROM warehouses w
JOIN (
    SELECT nation, COUNT(*) as nation_count
    FROM warehouses
    GROUP BY nation
) c ON w.nation = c.nation
GROUP BY w.nation, w.city, c.nation_count;
```

Comment: You should not post code-only answers. Instead explain a little what your query does. To get the additional nation count is easier done with a window function by the way: `select nation, city, count(*) as city_count, sum(count(*)) (partition by nation) as nation_count from warehouses group by nation, city order by nation, city;`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approch to get both city and country counts is to use `WITH ROLLUP`:

```
select 
  case when grouping(nation) then 'all nations' else nation end as nation,
  case when grouping(city) then 'all cities' else city end as city,
  count(*)
from warehouses
group by nation, city with rollup
order by nation is null, nation, city is null, city;
```

| nation | city | count(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| france | paris | 1 |
| france | all cities | 1 |
| germany | berlin | 1 |
| germany | all cities | 1 |
| italy | firenze | 1 |
| italy | roma | 2 |
| italy | torino | 1 |
| italy | all cities | 4 |
| all nations | all cities | 6 |

If you want to suppress the full total and want the nation total before the city totals, add a `HAVING` clause and change the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
select 
  nation,
  city,
  count(*)
from warehouses
group by nation, city with rollup
having nation is not null
order by nation, city is not null, city;
```

| nation | city | count(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| france | null | 1 |
| france | paris | 1 |
| germany | null | 1 |
| germany | berlin | 1 |
| italy | null | 4 |
| italy | firenze | 1 |
| italy | roma | 2 |
| italy | torino | 1 |

Or with `COALESCE` for a single nation-or-city column:

select
coalesce(city, nation) as name,
count(*)
from warehouses
group by nation, city with rollup
having nation is not null
order by nation, city is not null, city;

| name | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| france | 1 |
| paris | 1 |
| germany | 1 |
| berlin | 1 |
| italy | 4 |
| firenze | 1 |
| roma | 2 |
| torino | 1 |

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/4HERVYak

Comment: If you want two columns, one for the city count, one for the country count instead. See Umasha Kaumadi's answer and the query in my comment below it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Count() OVER()

```
    SELECT nation,city,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY NATION) cnt_nation,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY city) cnt_city
    FROM warehouses
```

Output

```
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| nation  |  city   | cnt_nation | cnt_city |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| germany | berlin  |          1 |        1 |
| italy   | firenze |          4 |        1 |
| france  | paris   |          1 |        1 |
| italy   | roma    |          4 |        2 |
| italy   | roma    |          4 |        2 |
| italy   | torino  |          4 |        1 |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/NeX-Evrz